# MYSQL JOIN ON X = IF(A,B,C) condition

Tags: mysql, join, substring, conditional-statements

I have two tables that have a field that have related fields with slightly different coding styes.  For example table `a` and `b` both with a field `idx`:

```
a.idx     b.idx
ABC       pfxABC
DEF       pfxDEF
GHI       GHI
JKL       JKL
```

As you can see in table b the IDX is sometimes populated with a prefix `pfx`

I want to join the tables stripping of `pfx` in the join condition inorder to normalize the data.  Something like:

```
SELECT * FROM a
LEFT JOIN b
ON a.idx = IF(SUBSTRING(b.idx,3)='pfx', SUBSTRING(b.idx FROM 4), b.idx);
```

However it seems that this never produces a match for `ABC = normalized(pfxABC)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To compare the first three characters to a literal

```
SUBSTRING(b.idx,1,3) = 'pfx'
                ^^
```

You need the form of SUBSTRING that takes three arguments; the second argument is the starting position, the third argument is the length.  In this example, the first three characters.

To test this:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING('abcdef',1,3)
```

returns `'abc'`

Compare to:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING('abcdef',3)
```

returns `'cdef'`

Reference: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_substring

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM a
LEFT JOIN b
ON CONCAT('pfx',a.idx) = b.idx
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM a
LEFT JOIN b
ON CONCAT('pfx',a.idx) = b.idx
  OR a.idx = b.idx
```